# WPF - Assign a command to a control's event

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, gantt-chart

I've a Telerik.RadGanttView component that implements some custom behavior, namely being able to adjust the zoom level of the timeline by using the scrollwheel over said timeline. This is done in the code-behind for the control with the following lines:

```
        _gantt = GetTemplateChild("Gantt") as RadGanttView;
        _gantt.PreviewMouseWheel += _gantt_PreviewMouseWheel;
```

_gantt_PreviousMouseWheel is the method that contains the logic to adjust the zoom level. While this works fine, I wanted to move the zooming logic to my view model and, if possible, bind the PreviousMouseWheel event to a command in my ViewModel rather than a method in my code-behind. I've tried using the Interaction.Triggers xaml tags, but while they did register the event, they only registered it when my mouse was NOT hovering over the timeline, which is the opposite of what I'm looking for.
Is there any way to achieve what is done in my code-behind and use it to call a command rather than a method in my code-behind?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Since you are already using Telerik, why not using its EventToCommandBehavior for this purpose?

Comment: I tried to do so, but unless I did something wrong, the event only seems to register when my mouse is NOT on the timeline when using EventToCommand

Comment: Then the timeline is likely intercepting the mousewheel messages.  Do you have some kind of active Telerik Behavior on the Timeline?  One solution might be to set it to `IsHitTestVisible="False"`  If that is not an option there are other ways.   Might be a bit tricky

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to achieve what is done in my code-behind and use it to call a command rather than a method in my code-behind?

Just invoke your command from the event handler programmatically:

```
_gantt = GetTemplateChild("Gantt") as RadGanttView;
_gantt.PreviewMouseWheel += (ss, ee) =>
{
    var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
        viewModel.YourCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

This is just as good as using an interaction trigger in the very same view to invoke the very same command as far as MVVM is concerned.

> This is what I would have liked to do, but due to how the files are structured within the project, I cannot access the DataContext's type without introducing a circular dependency.

Well, then you have obviosuly messed up your structure. A workaround would be to use the dynamic language runtime (DLR) and the `dynamic` keyword to bypass the static type checking at compile time:

```
_gantt.PreviewMouseWheel += (ss, ee) =>
{
    dynamic viewModel = DataContext;
    viewModel.YourCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

This is not any verse than binding to a potentially unexisiting property using a string identifier in XAML really.

Comment: This is what I would have liked to do, but due to how the files are structured within the project, I cannot access the DataContext's type without introducing a circular dependency, neither do I have the authority to change file locations

Comment: @Nougat, In that case, to answer your question, you need to explain your implementation in more detail. It would be best if you upload the Solution to GitHub.

Comment: @Nougat: Ouch. See my edited answer for a workaround then.